# .htaccess rewrite rule is also rewriting a different url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to make a couple pages on my site secure -- /renew and /renew-result. I have a script that takes the user's inputs from /renew, sends them offsite to complete something, and then they should be returned to /renew-result. This works without the https rewrite rule, but when I try to implement the rule (see below), instead of returning to /renew-result, the user is redirected to /renew.

Here's the relevant part of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^renew https://www.mydomain.com/renew [R,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^renew\-result https://www.mydomain.com/renew-result [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Replace `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$` with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and instead of `RewriteRule ^renew` should be `RewriteRule ^renew$` otherwise it is applied to any url starting with `/renew` and `/renew-result` also falls into that list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Why use HTTPS instead of SERVER_PORT?

Comment: Because the https connection can be done to the front-end (if exists) and normal from it to the web server, using port 80, but setting environment for the 'secure' connection with the help of `mod_rpaf`, for example. This is how I'm doing on my server - cachig nginx, which implements https connection too, normal connection to back-end apache, but providing info about the type of connection. Also back-end can run on other port, not on 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/renew-results` matches the URL starting with `/renew` (this is your first rule). There are few ways to bypass this 'problem'..

First (the longest URL to match goes first):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew-result https://www.mydomain.com/renew-result [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew https://www.mydomain.com/renew [R,L]
```

Second (limit URL to exact match with `$` at the end)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew$ https://www.mydomain.com/renew [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew-result$ https://www.mydomain.com/renew-result [R,L]
```

Third, combination of both cases in one rule. `^renew(-result)?$` matches only `/renew` or `/renew-result` capturing `-result` if it exists in request. While `https://www.mydomain.com/renew$1` redirects to https version of `/renew` or `/renew-result` if capture presents.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^renew(-result)?$ https://www.mydomain.com/renew$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With out testing, this is something similar to what I have.

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^renew https://www.domain.com/renew [L,R=301]`